# Redux. Pass state value to reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying implement Redux to my app. So, I created action, reducer, store etc... and now I have to pass state to reducer and change value of this parameter (boolean). I don't know what I'm doing wrong. An `alert` in reducer is triggered after click button, but `dialog` doesn't close. Any idea how to change value of `open`?

Action

```
export const checkPassword = () => ({
    type: "CHECK_PASSWORD"
  });
```

Component

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        checkPassword: () => dispatch({type: 'CHECK_PASSWORD'})
 };}

function mapStateToProps(state, open) {
   return {
       open: state.open,
   };}

class StartDialog extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { open: true };
  }

render() {
const actions = [ <FlatButton label="Submit" onClick={this.props.checkPassword} /> ];

return (
  <Dialog title="Welcome to the React App!" actions={actions} open={this.state.open} ></Dialog>
);}}

const StartForm = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(StartDialog);

export default StartForm;
```

Reducer

```
import { CHECK_PASSWORD } from "../constants/action-types";

const initialState = {
  open: true
};

const checkpasswordReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHECK_PASSWORD:
    alert('action!')
    return {...state, open: false};
  default:
    return state;
}};

export default checkpasswordReducer;
```

Store

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "../reducers/index";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && 
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

export default store;
```

Reducer index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import checkpasswordReducer from "./checkpasswordReducer";

export default combineReducers({ checkPassword: checkpasswordReducer 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open` will be in `props` not in `state`

change your render to this

```
<Dialog title="Welcome to the React App!" actions={actions} open={this.props.open} ></Dialog>
```

also in `mapStateToProps` function `open` value will be in state object so you don't need the second parameter in the function

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return {
       open: state.checkPassword.open,
   };
}
```

Comment: Now, I have an error: Failed prop type: The prop `open` is marked as required in `DialogInline`, but its value is `undefined`

Comment: can you post the how do create the store ?

Comment: sorry , but one more also post this file also `../reducers/index`

Comment: @Italik checkout the edit you need to change you `mapStateToProps` function

Comment: Ok, it's almost done. The one thing left is, that `dialog` should be open on start, because I pass to `initial state` true, but `dialog` it's close. When I change value to `true` in this line `return {...state, open: false};` it works properly. Why?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `redux` and reading the value from `store` you need to use it from `props` in your component. In short you should not have a `state` that is directly derivable from `props`. Change your component to below and it should work

```
class StartDialog extends Component {

    render() {
       const actions = [ <FlatButton label="Submit" onClick={this.props.checkPassword} /> ];

       return (
          <Dialog title="Welcome to the React App!" actions={actions} open={this.props.open} ></Dialog>
       );
    }
}
```

Also in your mapStateToProps you need to access the state correctly, If you are using combineReducers, you need to access the open value from the corresponding reducer

So if you use `combineReducer` like

```
const reducers = combineReducer({
   checkPassword:checkpasswordReducer
})
```

you need to use your `mapStateToProps` function like

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return {
       open: state.checkPassword.open,
   };
}
```

Comment: Now, I have an error: Failed prop type: The prop `open` is marked as required in `DialogInline`, but its value is `undefined`

Comment: Where is `DialogInline` component

Comment: Are you using combineReducers??

Comment: Oh, I meant `Dialog`. So, I need to add initial value to `open` in `Dialog` component. But it's weird because I wrote `const initilState` in reducer.

Comment: do you use combineReducer??

Comment: How is rootReducer written. Also check the updated answer

Comment: Ok, it's almost done. The one thing left is, that `dialog` should be open on start, because I pass to `initial state` true, but `dialog` it's close. When I change value to `true` in this line `return {...state, open: false};` it works properly. Why?

Comment: check in the render mthod what is the value of this.props.open